# Looping through files and auto filling a formula for each file using VBA

Tags: vba

I have the following VBA code:

```
        BD.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Formula = "=SUMIF('" & spath & "[" & itm & "]Sheet1'!$D$13:$D$" & LastRow2 & ",D" & BD.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row & ",OFFSET('" & spath & "[" & itm & "]Sheet1'!$D$13:$D$" & LastRow2 & ",0,MATCH(E" & BD.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row & ",'" & spath & "[" & itm & "]Sheet1'!$D$12:$R$12,0)-1))"
        With BD.Sheets("Sheet1")
            .Range("F" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).AutoFill Destination:=.Range("F" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row & ":F" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row)
        End With
```

(don't mind the very long SUMIF formula)

I'm looping through files using the following code:

```
spath = "P:\Actuary\Cash Flow Forecast\Annual and Quarterly Budget Data\"

''Retrieve the current files in directory
sfile = Dir(spath)
Do While sfile <> ""
    strFileNames = strFileNames & "," & sfile
    sfile = Dir()
Loop

''Open each file found
For Each itm In Split(strFileNames, ",")
    If itm <> "" Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(spath & itm)

        ''DO LOTS OF CALCULATIONS (code above included)

    End If
Next itm
```

For each file, say I have the following columns and what I want that formula to do is be placed on the next available cell in column 6 (as per my code, column 6 is Amount) and be dragged down until the last row of column 4 (again, as per my code, column 4 is RptLOB)

Ex:

```
RptLOB       ECMAccount  Amount
Disability   GEP         20   ---> (=SUMIF formula for file 1)
MSL          GEP         ..
Contingency  GEP         ..   ---> drag down to here (end of file 1)
Disability   GEP         30   ---> (=SUMIF formula for file 2)
MSL          GEP         ..
Contingency  GEP         ..   ---> drag down to here (end of file 2)
```

and so on for each file.

I thought my first code that actually places the SUMIF formula on the next available cell of the Amount column and dragging it down would work but it's only placing the SUMIF formula on the first row after Amount (Amount is in F1 - so only the 20 is showing) and nothing else is being dragged down...I'm not quite sure what is wrong with my code, whether it's the autofill or how it's reading each file.

If anyone has any insight to this problem or needs any more clarification, feel free to comment/ask.

Any help will be appreciated!

EDIT:
Even if I only use one file and put in another similar code

```
With BD.Sheets("Sheet1")
            .Range("F" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=.Range("F" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row & ":F" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
```

...only one value in F2 shows up and nothing underneath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that your Selection isn't acting on the open worksheet? I'm not sure where BD is set, but make sure it's all acting on what you think it's acting on, so to speak.

I might revise the code to be sure of that like this:

```
...
''Open each file found
For Each itm In Split(strFileNames, ",")
    If itm <> "" Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(spath & itm)
        Set ws = ws.sheets(whateversheet)

        ws.Range("F" & Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Formula = "=SUMIF('" & spath & "[" & itm & "]Sheet1'!$D$13:$D$" & LastRow2 & ",D" & BD.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row & ",OFFSET('" & spath & "[" & itm & "]Sheet1'!$D$13:$D$" & LastRow2 & ",0,MATCH(E" & BD.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row & ",'" & spath & "[" & itm & "]Sheet1'!$D$12:$R$12,0)-1))"
        With ws
            .Range("F" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).AutoFill Destination:=.Range("F" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row & ":F" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row)
        End With
    End If
Next itm
```

I might also make sure that

```
Rows.Count
```

is coming up correctly. Not sure how that's calculated, but it could cause some trouble when AutoFill is called.

Comment: I'll check out the `Rows.Count` and see if it has anything to do with that...the formula doesn't go to the open workbook, it goes in the BD workbook, sheet 1 which is why I had `BD.Sheets("Sheet1")`.